# Remove Protractor from from Aurelia TS WebPack?

Tags: webpack, protractor, aurelia

Is it possible to remove Protractor and all the related libraries from the Aurelia TypeScript Webpack skeleton project?

I tried npm uninstall Protractor and this was successful, but when I do NPM Start it fires off typescript errors that Aurelia-protractor can't find protractor. So I tried Typings uninstall Aurelia-protractor and it tells me that the Typings folder doesn't doesn't exist. Argh. Is there an easy way to get rid of Protractor and it's supporting modules?

Thanks.